# How to get count of checkbox checked which has same value in next td textbox dynamically created td?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Here i can select many check box's at same time And checkbox next td  value may have duplicates. If check  checkbox next td value has same value twice need to get count as 2 and so on..

my table

```
echo '<tr style = "text-align:left"><td><input type = "checkbox" class = "selected_id_v" name = "selectd_prcs[]" value = '.$value->labdetail.'></td><td>'.$value->id.'</td></tr>
```

what i tried

```
$(document).on('change','.selected_id_v',function () {
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
    var parseInt(checked_val) = $(this).parent().parent().children().eq(1).text();

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attribute equals selector

```js
$(document).on('change', '.selected_id_v', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    var checked_val = $(this).val();
    var $els = $('.selected_id_v[value="' + checked_val + '"]:checked');
    var count = $els.length;
    console.log(checked_val + ':' + count)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr style="text-align:left">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="selected_id_v" name="selectd_prcs[]" value='1'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="selected_id_v" name="selectd_prcs[]" value='2'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="selected_id_v" name="selectd_prcs[]" value='3'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="selected_id_v" name="selectd_prcs[]" value='3'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="selected_id_v" name="selectd_prcs[]" value='2'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="selected_id_v" name="selectd_prcs[]" value='2'>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: echo '<tr style = "text-align:left"><td><input type = "checkbox" class = "selected_id_v" name = "selectd_prcs[]" value = '.$value->labdetail.'></td><td>'.$value->id.'</td></tr>.if i check checkbox need to get $(this).parent().parent().children().eq(1).text() if this has same value need to count